# Help! I can't get back to my account!

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts

I have an old Stack Exchange account I've been using for years. I can still access it on other browsers, but I tried a new browser today.

When I tried to log in via Google [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), it suggested one of my Google accounts which I stupidly confirmed. My old account is linked to a different Google account, but now for the life of me I cannot manage to log in to that old one on this browser.

Every time I try to use the Google SSO button it simply automatically logs me in to this one. There doesn't seem to be any way to tell the site "I want to use a Google account, but **not the one I used last time**!"

Surely I'm missing something. This seems to make it impossible for two people with different accounts to share the same browser on the same computer.

I did try to clear my cache, but it didn't work. I will try harder, but in the meantime I'm posting here in the hopes I can bring this issue to the attention of someone with the power to fix it properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log in into Stack Overflow NOT using a Google account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377851/how-can-i-log-in-into-stack-overflow-not-using-a-google-account#comment1261198_377851) - also see that comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't signed-in to your Google account associated with your old Stack Exchange account on your new browser, you'll keep getting automatically logged in to SE with your current account if that's the only Google account you've signed-in to on your browser. In other words, since your current Google account, which has now been authorized to Stack Overflow, is the only account you've signed-in to on your new browser, you'll keep getting logged in with that account only.

There are two options:

1. Sign-in to the Google account associated with your old SE account on your new browser, then log out of your current account on SE. You should be able to log back in using the Google account associated with your old SE account.
2. Sign out of your current Google account on your browser and sign-in with the Google account associated with your old SE account. Log out of your current account on SE and you should be able to log back in using the Google account associated with your old SE account.

Another alternative is to add your current Google account as a login to your old SE account. This way, you can access your old account using your current Google account. Simply go to the [My logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) tab in the Settings tab of your profile and click on "Add more logins...". You can do this from a different browser (where you are already logged in with your old account). Then, on your new browser, log out and log back in, and you should be able to access your old account.

If you're still facing issues, fill the [Contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) (providing as many details as possible) and SE staff might be able to help you.

Comment: It might be helpful to move this answer over to the dupe [Stack Overflow sites force the wrong Google account when signing in with Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369527)